# How do I update an R package from Github within Conda?

Tags: git, anaconda, r, jupyter-notebook

I am experiencing an issue with the r-repr package in Anaconda's r-essentials package that prevents me from being able to execute code for time series in a jupyter notebook, as described here on the package's github: https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/issues/117

Happily, the above link also sees this issue fixed with commit 505a052 on the package's Github repository.

Sadly, I have had no success in implementing this update- conda does not offer this update to the r-repr package, and when I tried to download the commit from conda as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github  , I failed to get it to work, receiving this error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\envs\tester\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8fj3m_ve\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8fj3m_ve\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-8fj3m_ve\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Owner\Anaconda3\envs\tester\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-8fj3m_ve\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I even tried updating the package the way I would in R or R studio (install.packages('repr')) within a Jupyter notebook running the R kernel, but it ruined the entire Anaconda installation.

Does anyone know the best way to institute the commit in question or otherwise update this package in conda?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is running into this issue with the repr package running in a jupyter notebook, I have found that the workaround is not to update the package via github, nor to install the normal cran way (install.packages('repr')) from a jupyter notebook (as I had mentioned, doing so ruined my install).

Instead, I found that installing RStudio in anaconda, launching it, and using install.packages('repr') from there is what allowed me to successfully update the package. I was then able to use the same jupyter notebook without issue.